# Alt+Tab is a mess in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10

In Windows 7 I used Alt+Tab frequently to quickly jump to existing applications that I have recently opened and are working on.

In Windows 10 when you press Alt+Tab things seems like a mess. There is a lot of applications and things that I don't want there and have not started or opened myself. It does not make a lot of sense to have these applications there.

I use Alt+Tab to quickly navigate to other existing Applications that I have opened and are working on. At present there is a host of other things that makes it difficult to quickly navigate to the applications I'm working on. This basically removes much of the time-saving ability of Alt + Tab for me and frustrates me.

The following things are available when you press Alt + Tab which I would not like to be there:

- Store (Two windows for store ? Why two ?)
- 3 File Explorer or Control Panel Icons (No control panel or file explorer is open or loaded)
- Action Center
- Desktop
- Cortana
- Start
- Jump list for google chrome ??? What is this?
- Onenote (I don't use onenote)

Anybody have any idea how to get this back to the way it worked in Windows 7?

I don't want applications that is not in use or not relevant when you press Alt+Tab in Windows 10.

Comment: Are you sure you're using Windows-default Alt-Tab, not a 3rd party one like VistaSwitcher?

Comment: I've never seen your problem. Check if you have some external utility for task switching installed

Comment: Are you sure the applications are not actually running...?

Comment: They must be running but I have not started them or if I have started them I have closed them. I think it may perhaps be a setting somewhere that I have changed... Just wish I knew what setting.

Comment: have you tried the step from my answer?

Comment: I had this very same problem, check if you're running an outdated version of displayfusion.

Answer (score 5):

[There is a way to get the old Alt Tab dialog in Windows 10](http://winaero.com/blog/how-to-get-the-old-alt-tab-dialog-in-windows-10/) and disable the Task View-like new Alt+Tab dialog. You need to do the following:

- Open Registry Editor (regedit.exe).
- Go to the following Registry key:

  HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer
- Create a new 32-bit DWORD value named `AltTabSettings` and set it to `1`.

[image]

- Sign out from your Windows 10 session and sign in again.

Now you see the old ALT-Tab dialog

[image]

instead of the new Exposé like TaskView:

[image]

*(Picture)Source: [Winaero.com](http://winaero.com/blog/how-to-get-the-old-alt-tab-dialog-in-windows-10/)*

Comment: I find it interesting to note, that before Win 10 the alt-tab dialog lived somewhere outside of Explorer. That is if you kill explorer you still can do Alt-Tab. Not any more.

Comment: @zespri In Win10, Microsoft moved a lot (Startmenu, Action center) into a ShellExperirencehost.exe which loads DLL of the functionality. Maybe ALT+Tab also lives there